# SourceTree Revert a Revert

Tags: git, push, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I had a large project that was not under source control (I know - dumb). I was trying to get it set up with SourceTree, and couldn't figure out the combination of making a new repository through the client/making the repository on the website/making a repository from a working copy.

Long story short, I commited a single file hoping to see the entire source on the website, and when that didn't occur I reverse the commit. When I reverse the commit though, it got rid of 90% of my source code (as in it's not in the folder it was anymore, and now versions which are months old are).

This is my SourceTree history:
[image]

I'm not sure how to revert my revert, or commit/push all these files again. Moreso I'm trying to figure out how to get all my code back. It looks like I might be able to by looking at the history log but I was hoping it'd be simpler than that.

I'm somewhat unfamiliar with SourceTree and git and I should've looked up how to do it first, so it's my fault, but I thought I could figure it out and that it was simple enough. A

**Edit**: I was able to create an archive of the very first commit and all its files. It looks like this gets me back the source, but I'm not sure if this gets everything back in the correct state or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the following steps to get back all of the source code in its original state:

`right-click on first commit`=> `Archive...`

This gave a `.zip` of the entire source in its original state.